# Wall curve issues

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Hey I'm having issues curving something, for some reason the walls are being distorted and not staying on the path, my guess is there is too much of an angle but I was hoping to get some other input.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Ahhh, here it is https://pasteall.org/blend/95b24bd4dac34ccc97b6a637afd9c36d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your wall, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to reset the rotation. Put the wall at the same position as the curve's origin. Give your wall an *Array* modifier and a *Curve* modifier:

[image]